# Redirect visitors to a page saved in cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a main navigation and

1. Visitors click the main navigation -- a cookie remembers their last page.
2. Next time visitors enter the site from the root url they are redirected to that page.

How would you do it?... Any code would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the last location they visited like this, you could probably do this with a simple before filter on your ApplicationController.  In it you can add some logic to decide if you want to save the new location or retain the current one.

```
cookies.permanent[:last_visited_path] = request.request_uri
```

Then in the action pointed to by your root URL:

```
if cookies[:last_visited_path].present?
  redirect_to cookies[:last_visited_path]
end
```

You could also look into signing the cookie with cookies.permanent.signed if you want to prevent users from tampering with it.